# Base URL in Vue, Ionic, Vite breaks build

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, capacitor

please tell me when I add the base: /baseURL/ line to the vite.config.ts file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEKOi.png)

Then after the build the application does not start. without this line everything works fine. I need this line for the build on server!

with line base: '/testUrl/' build project is successful

Comment: Please add the code right inside your question instead of linking an image. Including the error shown in the build process will also help people understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### Try a common default value, such as this:

```
   baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080',
```